# Adding Drawable Images to RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I'm trying to add drawable images to my menu `RecyclerView`, however when I run the app, the images don't show up. Do I need to make the `menuImage` in my model class an Int so it knows what position the image needs to go in? Or do I need to change my syntax when I'm adding it to the array? Or do I need to `setImageDrawable` on my `menuImage` in my `MenuAdapter`? Thank you!

**My end result**

[image]

**What I have**

[image]

**menu_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/iconImageButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_photo_"
            android:contentDescription="@string/string_menu_icon_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menuLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_label"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuArrowImageView"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/right_chevron_"
            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_arrow" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**MenuItem.kt**

```
class MenuItem(val menuName: String = "", val menuImage: String = "")
```

**MenuAdapter.kt**

```
class MenuAdapter(var context: Context, var list: ArrayList<MenuItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder?.bindItems(list[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        fun bindItems(items: MenuItem) {
            val menuName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menuLabelTextView)
            val menuImage = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iconImageView)

            menuName.text = items.menuName
            Picasso.get().load(items.menuImage).into(menuImage)
        }
    }
}
```

**MenuActivity.kt**

```
lateinit var menuAdapter: MenuAdapter
val menuList = ArrayList<MenuItem>()

private fun createMenu() {

   menuAdapter = MenuAdapter(this, menuList)

  val menuRecycleView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.menuRecyclerView)
  menuRecycleView.apply {
       layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MenuActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
       adapter = menuAdapter
       setHasFixedSize(true)
  }

  menuList.add(MenuItem("My Profile", "${R.drawable.outline_person_}"))
  menuList.add(MenuItem("My Bookings", "${R.drawable.bookings_}"))
  menuList.add(MenuItem("Payments", "${R.drawable.payment_}"))
  menuList.add(MenuItem("On Going Jobs", "${R.drawable.on_going_jobs_}"))
  menuList.add(MenuItem("Settings", "${R.drawable.settings_}"))
}
```

Comment: In xml file try changing "app:srcCompat=" to "app:src="

Comment: @PRANAVSINGH, I get `error: attribute src (aka com.zwdalpha.skedaddle:src) not found.` if I just put `app:src=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `load(String)` with a `String`, which is [this method](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#load-java.lang.String-):

> Start an image request using the specified path. This is a convenience method for calling `load(Uri)`.
> This path may be a remote URL, file resource (prefixed with `file:`), content resource (prefixed with `content:`), **or android resource (prefixed with `android.resource:`)**.

You're just passing the bare resource ID int, as a string:

```
MenuItem("My Profile", "${R.drawable.outline_person_}")
```

I don't know what it wants specifically, it could be `"android.resource:${R.drawable.outline_person_}"` (the int) or it might be `"android.resource:R.drawable.outline_person_"` (the qualified ID name) - I'd guess the first one, but try the other if it doesn't work.

Your other option is using [`load(int)`](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#load-int-) which takes the actual resource ID int directly, so you'd define items as `MenuItem("My Profile", R.drawable.outline_person_)` - this is way better IMO, unless you really need it as a string for some reason (and you can't just convert it to a string when you need it).

I don't know if using `app:srcCompat` would be a problem, but you can try `android:src` instead if you're still seeing issues

(There should be some error info about this in your logs btw, a message from Picasso saying "couldn't load URL 1234567 or whatever", always check the logs for hints!)

Comment: Thank you, changed my `menuImage` to an `Int` and changing to `load(int)` in my `MenuAdapter` worked perfectly!!